# How to implement RSA SecurID in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, rsa

We have just started rolling out RSA SecurID tokens to our staff members. Most of our internal staff systems are custom in-house PHP applications, and it is my job to upgrade them to use the new RSA SecurID tokens for authentication.

I have no clue where to start... Does anyone have any ideas how to implement it in PHP?

We use MS Active Directory for our current staff authentication, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried that, but have you considered:

1. Using SecurID PAM module -> [some info here](http://www.softpanorama.org/Authentication/SecurID/installation_of_securid_client_on_suse.shtml).
2. and incorporating [PAM authentication in PHP](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM)
   ?

Answer (score 1):

looks like someone has done that here with PHP: 
http://charlietree.com/rsa-secure-id-authentication-in-php/

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.